# Learning Java Test-Driven Development

Tags: java, junit, tdd

I'm learning Java Test-Driven Development, with JUnit 4. I have been given a test scenarios, and have to write the implementation code, to get the tests to pass.

This is the test scenario:

```
package java;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertFalse;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class CallCenterTests {

  private final CallCenter callCenter = new CallCenter();
  private final LocalDateTime currentTime = LocalDateTime.of(2021, 1, 12, 17, 24);


  @Test
  public void testWillNotAcceptOutOfHours() {
    assertFalse(callCenter.willAcceptCallback(currentTime, LocalDateTime.of(2021, 1, 12, 20, 15)));
  }

  @Test
  public void testWillNotAcceptLessThanTwoHoursInFuture() {
    assertFalse(callCenter.willAcceptCallback(currentTime, LocalDateTime.of(2021, 1, 12, 18, 26)));
  }

  @Test
  public void testWillNotAcceptMoreThanSixWorkingDaysInFuture() {
    assertFalse(callCenter.willAcceptCallback(currentTime, LocalDateTime.of(2021, 1, 18, 12, 1)));
  }

}
```

This is what I know looking at the test scenarios:

There has to be written a class called CallCenter, where callCenter is the object reference.
We are using the LocalDateTime class, with a object reference called currentTime, which has parameter values of todays date and time.
There is a willAcceptCallBack method for the CallCenter class.

I am really new to Test-Driven Development, how would I write the method for this to get the tests to pass?

```
public boolean willAcceptCallBack(currentTime, LocalDateTime())
{
            // Potential scenarios:
            // 1st write a scenario that will not accept out of hours calls
            // 2nd write a scenario that will not accept calls less than 2 hours in the future
            // 3rd write a scenario that will accept calls more than 6 days in the future
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure TDD is really a factor here. The tests are already written for you and the method gives you the requirements. The rest is simply writing the logic to meet the requirements. You need to understand the problem, read the documentation of `LocalDateTime` (and possibly other `java.time` classes) to find what you need, research things you don't understand, and then apply what you've learned to the problem. Once you've solved the problem correctly the tests will pass.

Comment: `package java;` Do NOT do this. If you don't have a valid package name, just leave the package statement out. Or make up a package like com.example.whatever. But you should never use `java` or `javax` as a package name for your code.

Comment: You can always think of a good package name, only `java` isn’t one since this would imply that your code is part of the Java distribution (`LocalDateTime` is in a subpackage under the `java` package). Use something like `package edu.yourschool.mindgames2015.tddexercise;`. You can improve further from this point.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Ole V.V., from your answer, I've managed to work out roughly the implementation code, to get the tests to pass. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the real requirements are in the test method names. Like `testWillNotAcceptOutOfHours` means that `willAcceptCallback()` should return `false` if the time is out of hours. I hope you have been informed of your call center’s opening hours? Do they end at 20:00, for example? Asking just because I read from the test that 20:15 is outside hours.

Your method should return either `false` or `true` depending on the dates and times passed to it. Use the `isBefore` and/or `isAfter` methods of `LocalDateTime`. You will probably also need the `toLocalDate` and `toLocalTime` methods.